# discord.js get message id from interaction message

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to get message id from interaction message, but i can't get it :|

discord.js verson : ^13.1.0

```js
client.on('interactionCreate',async interaction => {

    if(interaction.commandName==='test') {
        let message = await interaction.reply({content:'testing...',ephemeral:true});
        console.log(message); //undefined
    }

});
```

Comment: I think it being ephemeral has something to do with it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [CommandInteraction#fetchReply()](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/replying-to-slash-commands.html#fetching-and-deleting-responses) method to fetch the Message instance of an initial response.

Example:

```js
   client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
       if (interaction.commandName === 'test') {
           interaction.reply({
               content: 'testing...',
               ephemeral: true,
           })
           const message = await interaction.fetchReply()
           console.log(message)
       }
   })
```

Comment: Ephemeral responses cannot be fetched but it's not a problem. Thank you!

Comment: If this was helpful, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

For latest version of Discord.js:

You can use the `fetchReply` property of [InteractionReplyOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/InteractionReplyOptions) to fetch the Message object after send it.

```js
let message = await interaction.reply({content:'testing...',ephemeral:true, fetchReply: true});
console.log(message); //Message Object
```